# Errors in hyperledger fabric multihost setup

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am manually trying to create hyperledger fabric multihost setup with crypto materials generated using fabric certificate authority . I am using AWS servers to deploy fabric . For this I did following steps

1- Create swarm network between 4 hosts

2- Generate  crypto materials in all hosts by calling fabric-ca-server using fabric-ca-client.

3- Generate genesis block using configtxgen tool in orderer machine.Here is configuration file for configtxgen

```
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: ../crypto-config/ordererOrganization/msp

    - &NeduetDean
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: NeduetDeanMSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: NeduetDeanMSP

        MSPDir: ../crypto-config/peerOrganization/dean.neduet.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: deanpeer
              Port: 7054

    - &degree
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: degreeMSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: degreeMSP

        MSPDir: ../crypto-config/peerOrganization/degree.neduet.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: degree
              Port: 7054

    - &Registrar
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: RegistrarMSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: RegistrarMSP

        MSPDir: ../crypto-config/peerOrganization/registrar.neduet.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: registrar
              Port: 7054

    - &Examination
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: ExaminationMSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: ExaminationMSP

        MSPDir: ../crypto-config/peerOrganization/examination.neduet.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: examination
              Port: 7054

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.  Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Global: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V1.1 for Global is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers and peers running v1.0.x,
        # but the modification of which would cause incompatibilities.  Users
        # should leave this flag set to true.
        V1_1: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # manipulated without concern for upgrading peers.  Set the value of the
    # capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V1.1 for Order is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers running v1.0.x, but the
        # modification of which  would cause incompatibilities.  Users should
        # leave this flag set to true.
        V1_1: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # manipulated without concern for upgrading orderers.  Set the value of the
    # capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V1.1 for Application is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all peers running v1.0.x, but the
        # modification of which would cause incompatibilities.  Users should
        # leave this flag set to true.
        V1_1: true

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:



################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:



################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    FourOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *NeduetDean
                    - *degree
                    - *Registrar
                    - *Examination
    FourOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                    - *NeduetDean
                    - *degree
                    - *Registrar
                    - *Examination
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

From another aws instance I spinup peer container and cli container with relevant  crypto materials mounted on both containers . Now when trying to create channel using this command `peer channel create -c obaid -o 10.0.0.1:7050` I get an error `Attempted to include a member which is not in the consortium` both in orderer logs and cli container . Can anyone help in fixing these issues?

These are my orderer and peer yaml files

### Orderer.yaml file

```
version: '3'

services:
    orderer1st:
        image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.1
        ports:
              - 7050:7050
        hostname: orderer
        networks:
              - fabricoverlay
        environment:
              - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
              - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
              - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
              - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
              - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
              - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp

        command: orderer
        volumes:
             - ./channel-configuration/orderer.genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
             - ./msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
             - ./peerOrganization:/var/hyperledger/allorgs
        deploy:
           placement:
              constraints: [node.hostname == ip-xxx-xx-45-231]

networks:
    fabricoverlay:
        external: true
```

### Peer and cli yaml file :

```
version : "3"

services:
   deanpeer:
     image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.1
     hostname: deanpeer.neduet.com
     networks:
       - fabricoverlay
     ports:
       - 7054:7054
     depends_on:
       - node_orderer1st
     environment:
       - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
       - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL= DEBUG
       - CORE_PEER_ENDORSER_ENABLED=true
       - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION= true
       - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER= leader
       - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
       - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
       - CORE_PEER_ID=deanpeer
       - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=deanpeer:7054
       - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=deanpeer:7054
       - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID= NeduetDeanMSP
       - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp

     volumes:
       -  /var/run/:/host/var/run/
       - ./Deansection/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp

     deploy:
        placement:
           constraints: [node.hostname == ip-172-31-19-22]


     command: peer node start
   cli:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=deanpeer:7054
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=NeduetDeanMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - ./Deansection/msp:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    networks:
        - fabricoverlay

    deploy:
        placement:
           constraints: [node.hostname == ip-xxx-31-19-22]


networks:
  fabricoverlay:
      external: true
```

Comment: You need to use `configtxgen` to create your channel transaction and then use the  `-f` flag with `peer channel create` to pass it in.  If you only run `peer channel create -c obaid -o 10.0.0.1:7050` then it tries to create the channel transaction locally from the defaults which is not what you want.

Comment: @GariSingh I tried with that but now I am getting error `2018-10-23 08:49:43.314 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 105 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp 10.0.0.10:7050->10.0.0.8:48566: read: connection reset by peer` . There is no issue in inspecting channel.tx using configtxgen tool but when I use that file in peer channel create command I am getting this error.

Comment: perhaps your peer CLI is not properly reading the file?  can you try doing everything from the same host / container where you generate the file?

Comment: @GariSingh Thanks that works . But I am wondering why it gives me that error when cli node is not running on same host/machine . I am simply copy/paste channel.tx from one machine to another

Comment: How exactly are you moving the file?  Are you using something like `scp`?

Comment: @GariSingh No just manually copy paste . Should I use scp ?

Comment: yeah ... it's binary content ... so I'd use `scp`